# Error related to Android Auto addendum - while publishing APK in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk, bundle

I want to release my app on google play store. After uploading the apk file to console. I am getting following error :
"you must accept the android auto addendum before uploading an android auto-enabled apk or android app bundle.you can do this from the advanced distribution page."

how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you've uploaded an APK/Bundle with [Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/cars) support.

**If you don't intend to release anything specific for Android Auto**, just check the manifest file and see if it contains anything releated to Android Auto (check for meta-data tags related to Android Auto). You can remove those and you'll be able to publish your app.

**If you want to release your app with Android Auto enabled**, you can find the settings related to accepting the terms.

- Go to your app on Play Console
- Go to Setup -> Advanced Settings from left panel
- Go to Form factors tab
- Select Add form factor -> Android Auto

It'll look like this once you select Android Auto:

[image: Android Auto Release Setup]

Ref: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-cars#opt_in

Comment: Awesome! You are legend!

Answer (score 1):

When we create a new app or an update of an existing app with `Android Auto` support, and we try to upload our .AAB o .APK, the `Google Play Console` will show the message:

> **You must accept the Android Auto Addendum before uploading an Android
> Auto-enabled APK or Android App Bundle. You can do this from the
> Advanced Distribution page**

We need to add a new form factor related to `Android Auto`:

`Setup` > `Advanced settings` > `Form factors` >  add `Android Auto` as form factor

[image: Google Play Jorgesys Android Auto]

Then accept the Android for Cars Terms of Service

[image: Google Play Jorgesys Android Auto]

And finally, release an `Android Auto` app bundle (.AAB) or .APK to a testing track

[image: Google Play Jorgesys Android Auto]